# How can you fix the environment variables when having Python 2.7 installed for both a x32 and x64 bit system?

Tags: python, environment-variables, environment

Hi I am in the end trying to get PyQt to convert a ui to a py file via pyuic. That being said, all of the commands I am trying are being rejected as inoperable. Images below! Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!!

[Image 1 is the cmd returning the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPEHT.png)

[Image 2 is the user environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Lczb.png)

[Image 3 is the system environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFQQT.png)

Comment: How come you have both installed?

Comment: Please enter text as text and not as images.

Comment: @blueberryfields I am relatively new to this but thought that having both installed would allow me to write for both x32 and x64 systems?

Comment: @Mazepaad If you need to target 32-bit systems (really? in 2018?), and you don't do anything that you expect to take advantage of 64-bit systems, it might be simpler to just only install 32-bit everything. Obviously 32-bit Python works on 64-bit systems, or it wouldn't work on your own system, right?

Comment: @abarnert LOL, unfortunately, someone I know needs the x32 version of the UI :( I had to modify to get this done... I like my 64 but your point takes precedence ... I will try uninstalling, modifying, rebooting and running! Thanks!

Comment: Look at using pip, virtualenv, and virtualenv wrapper for managing multiple python environments - that should solve that problem. For the specific issue you're seeing here, though, our env variables are just fine. You're literally trying to access a file that does not exist on your system

Comment: @abarnert Thanks guys! I am not sure what was wrong but I basically just ended up uninstalling everything related to python on my computer, and reinstalled just the X32 versions... was able to convert the file now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use a file which doesn't exist on your system.

According to the first image, the file you're attempting to access does not exist or is not called what you think it's called

Comment: okay, thank you! I think it has to be an issue with my system identifying each version of Python separately... ie. (C:/Python27(x32)) vs (C:/Python27(x64)). Do you know if this could be the issue? I have also run the commands as well as edit the environment variables with this incorporated but it still doesn't seem to help.

Comment: This has nothing to do with our environment variables. Your images clearly show you're trying to run a file that does not exist.

Comment: Okay, so my path is just wrong then? The file does exist and I am going to the file explorer and copying the path from there. I will have to check if it is saved elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: You sent a screen shot which very very clearly says the file does not exist. Just read the screen shot you shared, you'll see the error message right there.

Comment: (or, alternatively, this could be a permissions issue of some sort, where the OS pretends the file does not exist)

Comment: Thanks! ya, unsure what was wrong still. Had to basically clear everything related to python on my computer to have a fresh start.